# Selecting data from database by ID

Tags: php, mysql, select, html-table

I know this question maybe be easy but since I'm new to PHP and MySQL I don't know a solution to this.

I want to retrieve data from a table, but only for that one user. It's a system to check if their equipment is fixed, and I only want to the client to see his own equipment and not the others. So I think this is done by comparing the id in each table and if it is equal is shows.

Do you have any clue how I can do it? this is the code I have so far:

```
    <?php
// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
?>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<title>Verificar estado</title></head>
<body>
<?php
    //Tentativa de estabelecer uma ligação à BD
    $connection = new mysqli('****', '****', '******', '****');

    //Verificar se a ligação foi estabelecida com sucesso
    if (mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        echo "</h2>Erro no acesso à base de dados.</h2>" . mysqli_connect_error(); 
        exit();
        } 
    $user = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT id_user, id_ficha, avaria FROM fichas";

    //Executar a Query!
    $result = $connection->query($sql); 
    echo "<div id='listanomes'>User ID - ID Ficha - Avaria</div>";
    ?>
    <div id="lista">
    <div class="consultar">
    <?php
    while ($userproduto = $result-> fetch_object() ) {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->id_user . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->id_ficha . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $userproduto->avaria . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    } 
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    //Termina o script

        echo '<div class="foot">';
        echo '<p>Copyright © 2013 - Todos os direitos reservados - <a href="mailto:numica@numica.pt">Númica</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</body>';
        echo '</html>';
exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLE WHERE UR_KEY_NAME = USER_ID`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

to

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
```

And use this query with `WHERE`

```
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id_user, id_ficha, avaria FROM fichas WHERE id_user = $user";
```

Comment: hello i heard that we should not use direct session to query i also follow it but why should i dont use session directly to query it makes me confusion. can you clarify

Comment: now there is a problem with while loop. Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_fetch_object() on a non-object

Comment: @JoãoPereira It means this query is failing. echo this query and run it in `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @YadavChetan For preventing `SQL INJECTION`.

Comment: I'm trying like this: SELECT id_user, id_ficha, avaria FROM fichas WHERE id_user = id.users , it is giving an error about not knowing the column, isnt the "id.users" the right way to select data from other tables?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar but how can you inject?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing WHERE clause in your query

```
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id_user, id_ficha, avaria FROM fichas WHERE id_user = $user";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_fetch_object() on a non-object

Comment: it means your record is not found. Do some conditioning before proceesing.

Comment: well, already edited the query, and on phpmyadmin is works but on php it doesnt keep giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly and `fichas` table is the association table between user and equipment then your query should look like

```
$sql = "SELECT id_user, id_ficha, avaria FROM fichas f 
        LEFT JOIN equipment_table eq ON eq.id_ficha = f.id_ficha
        WHERE id_user = " . $id.";
```

This query will return all equipment for given user and you also will get the values from equipment table.

Don't forget to sanizite the `id` value (avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) - parse it to a number for example.

Comment: the variable $id is the same as my variable $user right? I'm getting an error on the fetch function :S

Comment: Yes, `$id` is `$user`, what error are you getting? The query has to be modified, I think you don't have `equipment_table` in your database. For more info on many-to-many association see http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php.

Comment: already solved the problem, I reasigned the _SESSION['id'] as I have in my index page and it is working, the name was wrong, thanks!